# How can i add elements to an existing array

Tags: php, arrays

How can i add elements to an existing array?

This is my code. As you can see, i already tried to add elements to an array by using this line of code.

```
$samlet[$key]['error'] = 'Dobbelt transaktion';
```

But this does not work. I already have a key called error in my array but its value is empty. I want to fill it out

```
foreach($samlet as $key)
{
        $transid=$key['transactionid'];
        $id=$key['cardid'];
        $time=strtotime($key['transactiontime']);
        $price = $key['pricebefordiscount'];
        $cardid = $key['cardid'];


     if ($price > 200000 )
    {
        $samlet[$key]['error'] = 'O/2000,-';
    }
      if ($price < 2500 )
    {
        $samlet[$key]['error'] = 'U/25,-';   
    }
    if(lookForNumbers(substr((string)$price, 0, -2)))
    {
        $samlet[$key]['error'] = '3 ens cifre i beløb';  
    }

  /*   if(isset($samlet[$key]))
        {*/

            foreach($samlet as $k1)
            {

             $time2=strtotime($k1['transactiontime']);

                if($key<$k1)
                {
                    if($k1['cardid']==$id)
                    {
                        if(compare($time,$time2))
                        {     
                            if (empty($k1['transactionid'])|| empty($key['transactionid'])) 
                            {
                                # code...
                            }      
                            else
                            {  
                            $samlet[$key]['error'] = 'Dobbelt transaktion';
                            $samlet[$k1]['error'] = 'Dobbelt transaktion';      
                            } 
                        }
                  /*  }*/
                }
            }
        }

    if ($cardid === '88888888')
    {
        $samlet[$key]['error'] = 'Testscan';
    }

}
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: `$samlet[$key]['error'][] = 'foo'` -- note extra `[]` at the end. This will make `$samlet[$key]['error']` an array of strings.

Comment: I just did this way and it works. But another problem appears. I hope you help again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use: `$samlet[$key]['error'][]` it will add new elements to the variable `$samlet[$key]['error']`

Do `print_r($samlet[$key]['error']);` to see that the value now contains an array of stored errors. Then you just loop through those elements to log, display, etc..

Comment: I just did this way and it works. But another problem appears. I hope you help again

Comment: @Zaz Sure, what is the problem?

Comment: But now my problem is

$time=$samlet[$key]

I have to replace it with

strtotime($key['transactiontime']

When i try to do this it wont work,  this is how i tried

 $time=$samlet(strtotime($key['transactiontime'])

Comment: there is a big difference between created and transactiontime. created = 2013-03-06 19:44:11 while transactiontime= 1362598242

Comment: @Zaz you should mark this question as answered and open another question regarding the other issue. It's not good to have multiple questions in the same question since it makes the site disorganized. =o) I'll check out the new question when you make it.